# Java EE Web application Servlet > Java Bean > class

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, javabeans

So i have a servlet that gets values from my JSP page. In my example i get the value of the radiobutton in the page.

```
searchListBean slb = new searchListBean();
slb.setType_id(Integer.parseInt((request.getParameter("optionsRadios"))));
```

then I put the value of the radiobutton inside the JavaBean with the variable Type_id. So for example the value of the radio button is 1. Now I'd like to retrieve that value which is 1 to another class so that I can use it inside the query. How do I do that? I have a code but it always shows 0. Thank you for your help.

```
String searchList = "";
searchListBean slb = new searchListBean();
int searchWhere = slb.getType_id();
System.out.println(searchWhere);
searchList = "SELECT PROD.PRODUCT_ID, PROD.PRODUCT_NAME, PRODTYPE.TYPE_NAME FROM PRODUCT PROD JOIN PRODUCT_TYPE PRODTYPE ON (PROD.PRODUCT_TYPE_ID = PRODTYPE.TYPE_ID) WHERE PRODTYPE.TYPE_ID = '" + searchWhere + "'";
```

I'm trying to put the value "1" inside the variable searchWhere but I cant. I cant use request.getParameter because the value is coming from the servlet not the JSP. again thanks!

Comment: Hey your question is unclear.

Comment: I'm not that good at explaining..
JSP radio button selected value is 1,
Servlet gets the value 1 using `request.getParameter("optionsRadios")`,
Servlet puts the value in JavaBean using `slb.setType_id();`,
Now the value 1 is in JavaBean Type_id and I'd like to retrieve it but 0 always comes out. My code for that is the second one.

Comment: In your second code snippet you create object `slb` and then you are trying to get `type_id` from it. It is 0, because it is an empty object. This is a place to start.
What you need to do is send the parameter `type_id` to the "another class".

Answer (score 0):

In your second code try to retrieve the value from object `searchListBean` you should create a variable like this:

```
  private searchListBean slb ;
```

Here retrieve the value

```
  int searchWhere = slb.getType_id();
```

Before you should remove this line:

```
searchListBean slb = new searchListBean();
```